# userid which in the private void sendMessage part. please help .child(userid); and chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in the `userid` in `sendMessage` method.

`.child(userid);` and `chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);`

Also I used `userid` in my `RegisterActivity` page but I think it is not about this.

> error: cannot find symbol variable userid

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView username;

    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    ImageButton btn_send;
    EditText text_send;

    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    List<Chat> mchat;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Intent ıntent;

    ValueEventListener seenListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MessageActivity.this,StartActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        btn_send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        text_send = findViewById(R.id.text_send);

        ıntent = getIntent();
        final String userid = ıntent.getStringExtra("userid");
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg = text_send.getText().toString();
                if(!msg.equals("")){
                    sendMessage(fuser.getUid(),userid,msg);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"You cannot send empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                text_send.setText("");
            }
        });


        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }else{
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }

                readMessages(fuser.getUid(),userid,user.getImageURL());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        seenMessage(userid);
    }

    private void seenMessage(final String userid){
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        seenListener = reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())&& chat.getSender().equals(userid)){
                        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("isseen",true);
                        snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(String sender,String receiver, String message){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender",sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver",receiver);
        hashMap.put("message",message);
        hashMap.put("isseen",false);

        reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

        final DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                .child(fuser.getUid())
                .child(userid);

        chatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void readMessages(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageURL){
        mchat = new ArrayList<>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mchat.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)){
                        mchat.add(chat);
                    }
                    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat,imageURL);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void status(String status){
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());

        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("status",status);

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        status("online");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        reference.removeEventListener(seenListener);
        status("offline");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initalized in `onCreate`

```
final String userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
```

Instead initialize the string `userid` as an instance variable accessible to the whole class.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Intent intent;

ValueEventListener seenListener;
String userid = "";
```

and in `onCreate` like this,

```
userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
```

Check for null when using userid always,

```
if(userid!=null) {
//do something
}
else {
Log.d("ClassName","userid is null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sir in sendMessage function parameters you change the name userid into sender, so you need to write sender instead of userId. check you function parameters